# Problema ao exibir modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando exibir um modal do bootstrap para o cliente, com uma mensagem de erro, meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage))
{
    <script>
        $('#modalError').modal('show');
    </script>

}



<div id="modalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@Model.ErrorMessage.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Mas esta aparecendo essa mensagem de erro: "O objeto não oferece suporte à propriedade ou método 'modal'"

O arquivo jquery esta referenciado na página normalmente.

Comment: basta por esse código "$('#modalError').modal('show');" dentro da função onload.

Answer (score 1):

Será que está faltando isso na chamada do modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```